# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Firstly it works fine But I don't know how to come this error in this page but this problem can be solve when i changed the code in view {{$training->first()->sectionsCount}} but my specification has been incorrect.
My complete error is:-

```
ErrorException in Training.php line 51: Trying to get property of non-object (View:resources/views/Training/index.blade.php)
```

My code in model is:-

```
public function sectionsCountRelation()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Schedule')->selectRaw('training_id, count(*) as count')->groupBy('training_id')->where('training_end_date','<',carbon::now());
```

}

```
public function getSectionsCountAttribute()
{
return $this->sectionsCountRelation->count;<!--This is line 51 -->
}
```

In controller is

```
public function index()
{

    $training = Training::with('sectionsCountRelation')->get();

    return view('Training.index',compact('training'));
 }
```

In View:-
 @foreach ($training as $training)

```
        <tr>

         <td>{{$i}}</td>
         <td>{{ $training->category }}</td>
         <td>{{ $training->topic }}</td>
         <td><a href="/schedule/before_held/{{$training->id}}">{{$training->sectionsCount}}</a></td>
         <td><a href="{{route('training.edit',$training->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Update</a></td>
         <td><a href="/schedule/create/{{$training->id}}" class="btn btn-info">Schedule</a></td>
         <td>
         {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['training.destroy', $training->id]]) !!}
         {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        <?php $i++;?>
         {!! Form::close() !!}
         </td>
     </tr>

 @endforeach
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are really asking for. But you already gave the answer `{{$training->first()->sectionsCount}} ` does it. And the problem is that `$training = Training::with('sectionsCountRelation')->get();` returns a collection (more than one object) and not an object. So you either select one object out of that collection (which `first()` does) or you loop through that collection (with `for .. each`) to show them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some Trainings that have no Schedule assigned. That means, `$this->sectionsCountRelation` returns `null` and you can't access `->count` on it. Try checking for `null`:

```
public function getSectionsCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->sectionsCountRelation === null ? 0 : $this->sectionsCountRelation->count;
}
```